# What will I need to add 2 monitors and wireless keyboard to an Inspiron 14z laptop running windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors

My son is in law school and wants the ability to add 2 monitors, a wireless keyboard, and mouse to use when at home. He wants to use two external monitors and not the laptop monitor. I bought everything but now how do I make it work and what other accessories will I need? He has a Dell Inspiron 14z laptop running Windows 8.

Comment: Can you clarify when you say 2 monitors if you mean the laptop screen and one additional monitor, or will the laptop run with the screen lid closed and you want 2 additional monitors on top of the closed laptop screen. If he wants the latter, I am not aware of a dock that is available for the 14z. If he wants the former, you just need an additional monitor that can accept HDMI connections along with a HDMI cable to connect from the laptop to the monitor. The wireless keyboard and mouse should only require a USB port to wirelessly transmit signals to the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: He wants to use two external monitors and not the laptop monitor

Comment: "I bought everything but now how do I make it work and what other accessories will I need?"  If you 'bought everything', then you shouldn't need anything. ;)  Can you tell us what you actually bought already?  What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Deb You already purchased the wireless keyboard and mouse which come with a tiny USB receiver that you connect to the laptop to send input wirelessly. To set up the monitors, your notebook should have two video-out ports (it looks like yours has VGA and HDMI ports as do most modern notebooks). Connect each monitor to one of those ports. These two videos might help: [1. Connecting 3 or more monitors](http://youtu.be/gn9VZq-nDj8). [2. Monitor ordering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf_TlAt1P9s)

Answer (score 1):

A [docking station is available for your Dell Inspiron 14z](http://web.archive.org/save/accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=332-0446). The cost is $99 as of Dec 2014. Since your son wants two external monitors with the laptop lid closed, you will need a docking station. The laptop can only accommodate one external display via HDMI. To utilize two external monitor, you need the docking station.

It is going to be a little messy since the dual video will require two different video cables. One cable will have to be DVI and the other will have to HDMI.

Ideally, when you purchase a LCD monitor, ideally they should have both DVI and HDMI connector on the LCD and come with both a DVI cable and HDMI cable.

[image]

If you decide this is just too much to deal with, you can just buy him one external monitor and have him use the laptop screen. This way, you don't need to buy a docking station. A YouTube video here explains the setup with just [one external screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2wCEnyP2as).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a HDMI splitter, but to my understanding both monitors will only be the main monitor. So no extension just 2 monitors mirroring each other.

update: You would then need a mobile workstation in order to use a docking station. With the docking station you are able to close your laptop and add multiple screens to it.

Comment: Its not clear what the OP means by 2 monitors. I'm not sure splitting the signal to duplicate it on two monitors is what OP would want.